# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: php

В файле php, когда регистрируюсь пишет синтаксическая ошибка на строке 123, а на строке 123 **`?>`**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    if ($login == '') unset($login);
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if ($password =='') unset($password);
}
if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {
    exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);
if (strlen($login) < 3 or strlen($login) > 15) {
    exit ("Логин должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из 15.");
}
if (strlen($password) < 3 or strlen($password) > 15) {
    exit ("Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из 15.");
}
if (!empty($_POST['fupload'])) {
    $fupload=$_POST['fupload'];
    $fupload = trim($fupload); 
    if ($fupload =='' or empty($fupload)) {
        unset($fupload);
    }
}
if (!isset($fupload) or empty($fupload) or $fupload =='') {
    $avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.jpg"; 
} else {
    $path_to_90_directory = 'avatars/';
    if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|     (PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {
        $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
        $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];   
        $target = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
        if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ; 
        }
        if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ;
        }
        if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory.$filename); 
        }
        $w = 90;  
        $w_src = imagesx($im); 
        $h_src = imagesy($im); 
        $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$w); 
        if ($w_src>$h_src) imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, round((max($w_src,$h_src)-min($w_src,$h_src))/2), 0, $w, $w, min($w_src,$h_src),  min($w_src,$h_src)); 
        if ($w_src<$h_src) imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src)); 
        if ($w_src==$h_src) imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, $w_src, $w_src); 
        $date=time(); 
        imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory.$date.".jpg");
        $avatar = $path_to_90_directory.$date.".jpg";
        $delfull = $path_to_90_directory.$filename; 
        unlink ($delfull);
    } else {
        exit ("Аватар должен быть в формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>");
    }
    $password = md5($password);
    $password = strrev($password);
    $password = $password."b3p6f";
    include ("bd.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
    }
    $result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,avatar)                  VALUES('$login','$password','$avatar')");
    if ($result2=='TRUE') {
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a                      href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
    }
    ?>
```

на 2 урокe остановился

Comment: Может у вас где-то поошибке уже прописан закрывающий тег?

Comment: Приведите строки 122-124

Comment: Я поражаюсь!

Comment: а где же 124-я строка? и было бы неплохо увидеть текст ошибки

Comment: О_о сколько человек хотело поправить вопрос, а я все их правки откатывал)  
P.S. возможно нужно поставить точку с запятой в строке 122 после }. Либо у Вас разное количество открывающих { и закрывающих }

Comment: всего 123 строки

Comment: Вот за это

    if ($result2=='TRUE')

надо руки отрывать. Потому что это отработает точно так же, как 

    if ($result2=='FALSE') // или if ($result2 == 'ololo')

И текст ошибки дайте. Подозреваю, вы где-то открыли `{` и не закрыли.

Comment: ошибку показывает вот эту ?>

Comment: Он не может показывать эту ошибку, ибо текст ошибки - это `"Syntax error: unexpected..."` и так далее) Вот мы ждем этот текст, т.к. его обычно достаточно просто перевести :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Z:\home\synape\www\save_user.php on line 123 вот этот

Comment: @антон У Вас разное количество { и }

Comment: @антон Предоставьте весь код! А также сообщите на какой части урока Вы сейчас остановились, так как этот скрипт содран вот отсюда: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=369
Сто процентно разное количество { и }

Comment: Вашу ж мать, этому `=='TRUE'` реально кто-то учит `О_О` Был бы ботнет - я б заддосил руселлер.ком `>_<` Хотя если сайт написан так же...)

[Воистину](http://bash.im/quote/40084)

Comment: Если бы Вы нормально форматировали код, то Вы бы сразу увидели свою ошибку. Я отформатировал его примерно так, как выглядит нормальный код, и **?>** с отступом как бы намекает.  
P.S. никогда не используйте TAB для отступа строки. 4 пробела  
P.P.S. `preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|     (PNG)$/'` так красивее `preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)$/i'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> на 2 урокe остановился

и правильно сделали, потому что данные видео уроки большой говнокод. Лучше книгу Д. Котерова почитайте

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Должно быть вот так!

```
  else {
       echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
    }} //тут две } о чем многократно постилось в комментах! 
?>
```

Вместо `if ($result2=='TRUE')`
Напишите `if ($result2)`

А то многих конструкция `if ($result2=='TRUE')` вгоняет в ужас)